# Polymorphic Association - Deleting comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, polymorphic-associations

I am creating an application that allows users to make comments on project postings created. I followed this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?) to set up polymorphic associations.

Everything works great per tutorial, but I have been trying to build in a delete method in my comment controller so comments can be deleted. I created a method in my comments controller called destroy.

Comments are made on my project postings. The partial for the comments are generated on the project pages and on the pages of the users who make the postings. When I delete on the project pages, it works great, but when I try to delete from the user page, I get the result below. How can I fix it so comments can be deleted by users whether they are deleting from the project page or from their own user pages?

```
Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController
```

comments_controller.rb

```
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    if @comment.destroy
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Comment deleted."
    end
  end
```

_comment.html.erb

```
<div class="comments">        
  <p><%= comment.content %></p>
  <span>
    By <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago

    <div class="pull-right">
<%= link_to "Destroy", [@commentable, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :comments

resources :projects do
  resources :comments
  member do
    get :following
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", [@commentable, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: added to my question above!